# Problem serving local files with vweb (V-lang's default server)

Tags: server, vlang

#### Description of the problem

According to V's doc, using vweb, in order to serve static files one just has to add the following line to a server:

```
app.mount_static_folder_at(os.resource_abs_path('dist'), '/content')
```

So, for instance: the following server is supposed to serve the content of the local directory ./dist at the address: `http://localhost:8080/content`

The complete code being :

```
import vweb 
import os

struct App {
    vweb.Context
}

fn main() {
    mut app := &App{}
    println(os.resource_abs_path('dist'))
    app.mount_static_folder_at(os.resource_abs_path('dist'), '/content')
    vweb.run(app, 8080)
}

["/"]
fn (mut app App) root() vweb.Result {
    return app.text('Hello from root')
}
```

#### Expected Behavior

The server is supposed to serve the content of the local directory ./dist at the address: `http://localhost:8080/content`

#### Current Behavior

`404 Not Found`

#### Reproduction Steps

`println(os.resource_abs_path('dist'))` yields

`C:\Users\serge\Documents\vue-tests\vue-tests-nomodules\v2\dist`

Which is correct, plus:

`ls` lists

```
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         2/11/2023   6:45 PM                dist
d-----         2/11/2023   6:45 PM                src
-a----         2/11/2023   5:53 PM            139 .editorconfig
-a----         2/11/2023   5:53 PM            148 .gitattributes
-a----         2/11/2023   5:53 PM            237 .gitignore
-a----         2/11/2023   6:06 PM             85 v.mod
-a----         2/12/2023  12:56 PM        2037248 v2.exe


PS C:\Users\serge\Documents\vue-tests\vue-tests-nomodules\v2> ls .\dist\


    Directory: C:\Users\serge\Documents\vue-tests\vue-tests-nomodules\v2\dist


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         2/11/2023   6:32 PM            295 app.html
-a----         2/11/2023   6:42 PM            295 index.html
```

#### Possible Solution

*No response*

#### Additional Information/Context

[image: Screenshot (257)]

*No response*

#### V version

V 0.3.3 90591eb

#### Environment details (OS name and version, etc.)

Windows 11

Comment: First, the 'vweb' module is missing from your example. You need to import it. Once imported, you need to start the server using the 'v run' command. When launching the server, the correct address to enter in the browser is (according to your example): 'http://localhost:8080/' and not 'http://localhost:8080/content'. Finally, if nothing happens despite this, you will need to fix permission issues on your OS.

Comment: Thanks. It does not work on Mac OS or Windows. I filed an issue with V.

Comment: For me with your 'fixed code' it work without any problem ( on Windows 11 and Ubuntu ). Its probably not an issue with vlang on my opinion. Do you use address : 'localhost:8080' without '/content' ?

Comment: 'localhost:8080' without '/content' works, but 'localhost:8080/content' doesn't.

Comment: The amended version doen't work under Linux either. It could be linked a specific version of V-lang.

Comment: The "mount_static_folder_at()" function is used to make files contained in a directory as "static files." The "v" documentation specifies that to access the static resources from the previously declared directory, you must provide the link to the resource itself, not just its directory. In your example:

"http://localhost:8080/content"

becomes:

http://localhost:8080/content/app.html

or:

http://localhost:8080/content/index.html

The Vweb server should then return the desired page.

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: For me, all works. ( with Ubuntu and Windows 11 ) : https://pasteboard.co/7ogCmMiXUHFe.png
make sure all the files are in the correct directories and use correct URL and your code must be similar to your corrected example like explain previously.

Answer (score 1):

A bit too late, but I had a similar issue lately.

Apparently, it does matter how you start the `vweb` server.

```
// <my_project>/src/main.v
const (
    assets_dir_name   = 'assets'
    assets_mount_path = os.join_path(os.resource_abs_path('.'), 'src', assets_dir_name) // assets_mount_path == ./src/assets
)

fn new_app() &App {
    mut app := &App{}
    // note: /assets/css and /assets/js as `mount_path` of mount_static_folder_at() must start with forward-slash (/)
    // all *.css in assets_mount_path/css -> /assets/css
    // all *.js in assets_mount_path/js -> /assets/js
    app.mount_static_folder_at(os.join_path(assets_mount_path, 'css'), '/assets/css')
    app.mount_static_folder_at(os.join_path(assets_mount_path, 'js'), '/assets/js')
    return app
}

fn main() {
    vweb.run_at(new_app(), vweb.RunParams{
        host: server_host
        port: server_http_port
        family: .ip
    }) or { panic(err) }
}
```

and in my temaplte

```
    <title>${page_title}</title>
    @css '/assets/css/main.css'
    @js '/assets/js/main.js'
```

You could also use path in href like

```html
<script src="/assets/js/main.js" defer></script>
```

In order to run this properly just

`v run .` from your <my_project> and **not** from `<project_dir>/src`

[image]